# How does Doctrine2 DQL simulates Oracle LIMIT and OFFSET?

Tags: oracle, doctrine-orm, dql

So I'm investigating Doctrine source code for learning purposes. Already searched within entire code base and could not localize where do they implement such abstraction to generate queries for Oracle simulating LIMIT and OFFSET.

Where is it? Are they using the strategy pattern to achieve that? Case not, what pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[protected function doModifyLimitQuery($query, $limit, $offset = null)](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/OraclePlatform.php#L717)